# How to wirte a pl/sql developer plugin to insert into the special text to the cursor position of current window?

Tags: plugins, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm study how to develop plsql-developer plugin by the plugindoc.pdf and I'm using C++.

Now,I want to  insert into the special text to  the cursor position of current window,

The function IDE_SetText will Covered the old text in  the editor of current window.

IDE_GetCursorX and IDE_GetCursorY get the position of the cursor in the current editor.

What's next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PL/SQL Developer editor window implements the standard WinAPI editing control. Use WinAPI messages to interact with the window.

```
void SetSelection(char *s)
{
  int H;

  H = IDE_GetEditorHandle();
  if (H > 0)
  {
    SendMessage((HWND)H, EM_REPLACESEL, true, (int)s);
  }
}
```